# How to iterate through two arrays and find the GCD of the corresponding elements and store these in a third array? (C)

Tags: arrays, c, loops

So I am tasked with doing the following:

I am given two arrays with a sentinel value. I need to create a function that will iterate through these, finds the GCD of the corresponding elements (ex: array1[0] and array2[0]), and store the result into a result array until it hits the sentinel value.

I have tried the 0th element and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Recursive `gcd()` is faster.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#define SENTINEL    255   // or a negative number

int gcd (int p, int q) { // Recursive
    if (q) return gcd (q, p % q);
    return p;
}

void GCD_array (int a1[], int a2[], int ans[]) {
    for (int ni = 0; !(SENTINEL == a1[ni] || SENTINEL == a2[ni]); ++ni) {
        ans[ni] = gcd (a1[ni], a2[ni]);
    }
}

int main (void) {

    int array1[] = {245,  92, 16,  1,   3, 22, SENTINEL};
    int array2[] = {57,  226, 240, 15,  22,  3, SENTINEL};
    int count =  sizeof (array1) / sizeof (int) -1;
    int ans [count];
    GCD_array (array1, array2, ans);
    for (int ai = 0; ai < count; ++ai)
        printf ("gcd (%d, %d) = %d\n", array1[ai], array2[ai], ans[ai]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am not concerned with optimization with this code, rather I am going for simplification and readability which is why I didn't use recursion. How would I implement your suggested answer until it hits 255 in the arrays? Also, for my purposes, the part where it creates the GCD array needs to be in the same function as where it calculates the GCD.

Comment: @RainyVengeance just check for `sentinel` in input arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Modify GCD as shown to accept two integers

```
int GCD(int var1, int var2) {
int tempvar1;
int tempvar2;
int result;
int remainder;
int i;

tempvar1 = var1;
tempvar2 = var2;
```

In the main, add code to loop through the arrays

```
 int i = 0;
 int array_len = sizeof(array1)/4;
 
 int array_result[array_len];
 
  while ( (i < array_len) && (array1[i] != 255))
    {
      array_result[i] = GCD (array1[i], array2[i]);
      
      printf ("%d\n", array_result[i]);
      ++i;

    }
```

Comment: Your answer is perfect, but instead of a for loop, can you show me how you would use a while loop until it hits 255 and iterate through it that way?